# jquery-ui switchClass() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm having trouble getting the switchClass function to fade nicely like it does in the example on the jquery site. Basically the timing doesn't seem to have any effect, I've tried from 40000-4 but makes no difference.

I've posted a fiddle below (which explains better) but here's the code I'm using. There's two divs which are meant to switch class so the background image is different. I'm using different methods for each div but they both give exactly the same result even though one uses switchClass the other uses addClass.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.iamatrainer').hover(function(){
        $(this).switchClass('iamatrainer', 'iamatrainerhover', 400, 'easeInOutQuad');
        }, function(){
            $(this).switchClass('iamatrainerhover', 'iamatrainer', 400, 'easeInOutQuad');
    });
    $('.iusetrainer').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('iusetrainerhover', 400);
        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('iusetrainerhover', 400);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KJbA8/

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have jQueryUI loaded? The switchClass method isn't a part of jQuery. Your fiddle is throwing JS Console errors about it.

You don't really need JS for this. Just setting the `:hover` on the `.iamatrainer` and `.iusetrainer` elements works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/y3ALr/3/

Also, if you must use a background image...

1. Make sure you're using some reasonably accessible image replacement technique
2. Consider using sprites and :hover offsets so you don't get that nasty delay.

Comment: yeah jquery is loaded ok. whats the best way to have one image replace the other using a fade?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) pseudo-selector and [`css transitions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

## CSS:

```
.iamatrainer{
    background:url(http://renegadeox.com/iamatrainer.png);
    height:70px;
    width:512px;
    transition: background 0.3s linear;
}

.iamatrainer:hover{
    background:url(http://renegadeox.com/iamatrainerhover.png);
    height:70px;
    width:512px;
    transition: background 0.3s linear;
}
```

## Here is your updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/KJbA8/2/).

Also, you'd better merge images in one and use [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) for `:hover` state

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I think this is the way to do it but the transition on the fiddle still is pretty instant. I wanted it to fade to the blue colour, at the moment it just switches

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: transitions on background images only works in webkit at the moment. If

Comment: I'm using firefox... I take it thats the problem then